# Converting tensor to numpy array in custom loss function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

Here is my custom loss function:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import cmath

epsylon=np.finfo(float).eps

def to_array(tensor):
    return tf.make_ndarray(tensor)


def addError(test,range_min,range_max,result):
    err = abs(log(range_max/max(range_min,epsylon)))
    if range_min <= test <= range_max:
        result.append(err)
    else:
        e1=abs(log(test/max(range_min,epsylon)))
        e2=abs(log(test/max(range_max,epsylon)))
        result.append( min(e1,e2) / max(err,epsylon) *100 + err)


def rangeLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    #print(type(yPred))
    a_pred=to_array(yPred)
    a_true=to_array(yTrue)

    result=[]

    for i in range(a_true.size):
        range_min=abs(a_pred[i*2])
        range_max=abs(a_pred[i*2+1])
        test= abs(a_true[i])

        addError(test,range_min,range_max,result)


    return tf.constant(result)
```

When I run training, it fails with

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:591 MakeNdarray
        shape = [d.size for d in tensor.tensor_shape.dim]

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'
```

When I modify to_array to use proto tensor

```
def to_array(tensor):
    proto_tensor = tf.make_tensor_proto(tensor)
    return tf.make_ndarray(proto_tensor)
```

I get following error:

```
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:451 make_tensor_proto
        _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:328 _AssertCompatible
        raise TypeError("Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.")

    TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.
```

Another option I've tried was `tensor.numpy()`, which resulted in following error:

```
    <ipython-input-20-0a8051a4a034>:8 to_array
        return tensor.numpy()

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

And of course there is `tensor.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())`, which fails too

How do I do this?

Comment: what are the shapes of yTrue, yPred? what is a_prod?

Comment: both yTrue and yProd are column vectors, yProd has 2x elements of yTrue. The purpose behind this is that I'd like to get range estimate instead of single point estimate for yTrue. `a_prod` is a typo

Comment: ok, so following what you said yTrue has shape (N, 1) yPred has shape (2N, 1)... did I understand correctly?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani yes

Comment: ok, I've never seen true and pred with a different number of samples, and I have doubt that keras can handle this. I think that the starting point is to reshape your data in this format yTrue (N, 1) yPred (N, 2)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani how would I declare an output  layer that returns data in shape of (N,2)?

Comment: simply having yTrue with shape (N,2) and a final dense layer like this Dense(2)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani yes, you were right. I was able to implement this algorithm by slicing the yPred into 2 vectors and working separately with each of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by slicing the original tensor. Here is the code:

```
def above_zero(value):
    return tf.math.maximum(value,np.finfo(float).eps)

def range_loss(yTrue,yPred):
    #shapes: yTrue: (None,1)
    #        yPred: (None,2)
    yTrueSize=yTrue.shape[1]
    min=above_zero(tf.math.abs(yPred[:,:yTrueSize]))
    max=above_zero(tf.math.abs(yPred[:,yTrueSize:]))

    #following step should not be needed, but let's do it just in case
    yTrue=above_zero(tf.math.abs(yTrue))

    baseError    = tf.math.abs(tf.math.log(max/min))
    baseErrorDiv = above_zero(baseError)

    topRange     = tf.math.maximum(min,max)
    bottomRange  = tf.math.minimum(min,max)

    extraError = tf.math.maximum(0.0,tf.math.log(yTrue/topRange))+tf.math.maximum(0.0,tf.math.log(bottomRange/yTrue))
    extraError /= baseErrorDiv

    totalError=tf.math.pow(extraError,2.0)*100+tf.math.pow(baseError,2.0)

    return tf.math.reduce_sum(totalError)
```